# jquery masonry responsive alignment with bootstrap on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having this output whenever I resize the browser

[image]

The boxes should be closed to each other. I wonder how can I do this with jquery masonry or css. Any help/suggestion would do.

Note: I can resolve this by disabling the responsiveness of Masonry plugin but the **responsive-css** of bootstrap wont work.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what happens is that, when resizing the window from full-screen to really small width, firstly the masonry plugin does its job by changing the top of each article, and afterwards bootstrap's javascript kicks in and changes col-md containers' width to fit the whole page, forcing the text to wrap in less lines, so the height of the col-md container becomes smaller and leaves a lot of space between the items.

What worked for me, was adding a col-xs class (which is used on small screens)  to my col-md containers.

Cheers!